# How to use Stripe Apis on AWS Lambda in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, stripe-payments, aws-lambda

I am going to build a backend using Stripe api on AWS Lambda.
But I can't import stripe library.

```
import stripe
```

This line gives me this error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: How are you installing the stripe library?

Comment: It's what I want you to help me. :)

Comment: Ok, so it seems you don't know you have to install libraries yourself. It is easy to find examples but will post when later when I get in front of a computer

Comment: Here is an example of how people deploy. I can answer with a more specific example, but is this what you are looking for? https://medium.com/@AdamRNeary/a-gulp-workflow-for-amazon-lambda-61c2afd723b6#.1dk1m6bh1

Answer (score 8):

The Stripe python libraries need to be installed to the same folder as the python script you are writing.

The pip command to do this is:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=/full/local/path/to/your/python/script" --upgrade stripe
```

This will actually install the libraries into the "lib" folder in the path you indicated. Copy everything from /full/local/path/to/your/python/script/lib/python2.7/site-packages to /full/local/path/to/your/python/script

Your directory will then look something like this:

```
./main.py
./requests/
./requests-2.13.0-py2.7.egg-info/
./stripe/
./stripe-1.55.0-py2.7.egg-info/
```

Zip up those files and then upload that ZIP file to AWS Lambda.

I know this question is over a year old, but it's still unanswered, and is what still turned up when I searched for this same problem, so here is how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to James Eberhardt's answer using --target will place files directly into desired location.

```
pip install --target="/full/local/path/to/your/python/script" --upgrade stripe
```